# What would cause an installed application to not be recognized as such?

Tags: apt, dpkg, gdb

I need to revert my version of gdb back to a previous release so that it is compatible with a certain tool. I currently have gdb 7.7.1 installed. If I enter `gdb` into the terminal and hit enter, gdb runs. However, when I run `sudo apt-get remove gdb`, it says this:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove gdb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gdb' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

This is the case when I use `sudo dpkg -r gdb` as well. How can I fix this so that the program is first recognized and then removable?

```
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
3.13.0-53-generic
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First find out what binary will be executed when you run `gdb` using `which` command:

```
which gdb
```

it's outputs a path like: `/usr/bin/gdb` then we should search which package installed this file using `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/gdb
```

or even:

```
dpkg -S $(which gdb)
```

so it gives us a package name like :`gdb: /usr/bin/gdb`. then remove that package: `sudo apt remove gdb` in this case.

---

As an alternative you can just reinstall the older version, first see what versions are available to you:

```
apt-cache madison gdb | grep -iv sou
  gdb | 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
  gdb | 7.11-0ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

then install the older version it will take care of newer version removal itself:

```
$ sudo apt install gdb=7.11-0ubuntu1

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  gdb
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: FYI - Thanks to your solution I was able to detect that it was called 'gdb-minimal' from dpkg -S